# Extracting numeric value from text in an xml node

Tags: xml, string, powershell

I currently have a log file that looks similar to this:

```
<AutoRun>
    <Info>Log file enabled: C:\Sync.xml</Info>
    <Info>Exit attribute has been enabled.</Info>
    <Info>Launching command: Run</Info>
    <Run>
        <Info></Info>
        <Info></Info>
    </Run>
    <Infolog>
                 get    Number of failures: 0
                 Number of Warnings: 0
                 Have resolvable Warnings: False
                 Number of Operations: 5
                 Number of Conflicts: 0

                 Get C:\ with ChangeType: None and Status: Replacing.
                 Get C:\ with ChangeType: None and Status: Replacing.
                 Get C:\ with ChangeType: None and Status: Replacing.
    </Infolog>
</AutoRun>
```

I'm trying to parse out the text in  and do the following:

1. Cleanly get the text line

   Example: Number of failures: 0, Number of Warnings: 0
2. Get the value after :

I get the text by doing this:

```
[xml]$Log = get-content "C:\Synchronize.xml"
$results = $Log.AutoRun.Infolog
```

And thought I could retrieve the line by doing this:

```
Select-String -InputObject $a -Pattern 'Number of failures:'
```

But this is returning everything in the infolog node, not just the line I'm after.  I'm struggling with understanding how to accomplish these two tasks.

This is what I ended up with after reading the first two suggestions.:

```
string[]]$Log = get-content "C:\Synchronize.xml" 
$results = $Log | Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures:\s+(\d+)' | %{$_.Matches.Groups.Value[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Select-String takes a `String[]` for the InputObject argument.  However, the XML element is a single string with embedded newline characters.  You are passing in that single string and searching in that rather than the individual lines.

If you want to use this string with Select-String, you need to split it into lines first.  You do this using the String.Split method.  You can also apply String.Trim to the result to trim the whitespace for a cleaner line of text.

```
$results = $Log.AutoRun.Infolog.Split("`n") | % { $_.Trim() }
$results | Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures:'
```

Note that PowerShell behaves differently when InputObject is piped in versus used as a parameter so you need to pipe the `string[]` in to search each string.

From https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx :

> Using the InputObject parameter is not the same as piping strings to
>   Select-String. The differences are as follows:
>
> -- When you pipe more than one string (a "collection") to Select-String, Select-String searches for the specified text in each
>   string and returns each string that contains the search text.
>
> -- When you use the InputObject parameter to submit a collection of strings, Select-String treats the collection as a single combined
>   string and returns the strings as a unit if it finds the search text
>   in any string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! It actually helped me change the code to as follows:

[string[]]$Log = get-content "C:\Synchronize.xml"
$results = | Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures:'

This returns the string: 

     get    Number of failures: 0

And then I used Matt's example to get at the number:
[string[]]$Log = get-content "C:\Synchronize.xml"
$results = |Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures:\s+(\d+)' | %{$_.Matches.Groups.Value[1]}

Answer (score 0):

There is more to this but the root of your issue is that the text withing the InfoLog take is being read as one single string. If you look at this you will get results more inline with what you expect. I dont think this is the best solution but it highlights the issue

```
$Log.AutoRun.Infolog -split "[`r`n]" | Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures'
```

`Select-String` will return the string containing the match. Therefore in your example it is returning the match you requested. [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29154145/3829407) covers the reason for this in more detail that would be redundant to mention again here.

Think you need at least PowerShell 3.0 for this but you can isolate the number and the extract it from the matches object that `Select-String` returns.

```
$Log.AutoRun.Infolog | Select-String -Pattern 'Number of failures:\s+(\d+)' | %{$_.Matches.Groups.Value[1]}
```

`Select-String` returns `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo` by default not a basic string. They have various properties concerning the matches defined. The whole match is returned by default when no properties are specified. However delving into the properties I want to extract the capture group defined in the regex `(\d+)`. If you remove the properties from right to left you can get a better idea of what is in there.

- `$_.Matches.Groups.Value`
- `$_.Matches.Groups`
- `$_.Matches`

The `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object` that I forgot to remove. It is possible for more than one match to be returned. We treat the results as an array and check each one.

Assuming the line always has digits on it that will return just the number after the ":". If it has a change to return words you could just use `\S+` in place of `\d+`

Comment: Thank you for the select-string pattern.  Can you explain a bit more on how the %{$_.Matches.Groups.Value[1]} operates?

Comment: @Mike small explanation added.